# What is the difference between Model#remove and Model.remove in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In the Mongoose API docs, there is [Model#remove](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.remove), and there is [Model.remove](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-remove).

Can somebody explain, in layman terms, what is the difference between these two? They appears to accept different parameter(s). And why is one using dot and the other using hash? I need an even clearer explanation besides the one in the API docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Model#remove` is an instance method, `Model.remove` is a class method.

In other words, say that you have a model called `Users`. To remove something from the collection that belongs to that model, you have two options (this example is a bit contrived):

```
Users.findOne(CONDITION, function(err, user) {
  if (err) throw err;
  user.remove(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // user is removed
  });
});
```

This uses `Model#remove`: you have an instance of the model stored in `user`, and you remove that instance from the database by calling the `remove` method on the instance.

The other option:

```
Users.remove(COND, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // user_s_ matching COND have been removed
});
```

Basically, `Model#remove` is used to remove a single document for an instance that you already have, and `Model.remove` is used to remove possibly a list of documents that match a particular condition, or a document that you don't necessarily first want to retrieve from the database.